# adding function without using JSX compiler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

just I want to ask how can I add click event without using JSX compiler in react.right now my event is not execute and the event is not attach to elemant

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var MYCOMPONENT = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'MYCOMPONENT',
    handleClick: function (e) {
        console.log('You clicked');
    },
    render: function (){     
        var listUser = this.props.data.map(function(item){

                return(
                    React.DOM.div(
                        {
                            className: 'panel panel-default staff-reception ' + item.statusType.toLocaleLowerCase() + 'Office',
                            'ng-click': 'showUserDetails(user)',
                            onClick: this.handleClick
                        },
                React.DOM.div({ className: 'panel-body' },React.DOM.span(null, item.firstName + ' ' + item.lastName + ' ' + item.directDial + ' Ext:' + item.voiceMailExt)
             )
             )
             );
        });

        return (React.DOM.div({className:'col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4'}, listUser));
    }
});
```

Comment: Why you dont use synthetic events in your component ? What is wrong?

Comment: can you show me how ?

Comment: my problem with using JSX is not asp.net friendly ?

Comment: i dont know about asp.new actually you can use react-tool to compile your JSX code into JavaScrips [here is link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tools)

Comment: JSX is not required to take advantage of the synthetic event system in React.

Comment: @user3277743 [ASP.NET and React integration](http://reactjs.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem probably has to do with `this` binding. Inside the `map` function:

```
var listUser = this.props.data.map(function(item){
  // ...
    onClick: this.handleClick
  // ...
});
```

`this` is no longer bound to the component instance, so `this.handleClick` is `undefined`. [`Array#map` takes a `thisArg` argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) that allows you to specify the value of `this` inside the function:

> If a `thisArg` parameter is provided to map, it will be passed to callback when invoked, for use as its `this` value. Otherwise, the value `undefined` will be passed for use as its `this` value.

So, specify the component instance as the `thisArg` parameter:

```
var listUser = this.props.data.map(function(item){
  // ...
    onClick: this.handleClick
  // ...
}, this);
```

Here is a JSFiddle using your code (but with the `thisArg` added) to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/9f89ynoL/